# How can I set up formatters in SlickGrid?

Tags: jquery, slickgrid, formatter

I already did my studies, I know how to make a custom formatter, or editor and how to use it.
My problem is, I am unable to set up, or use a formatter.
My structure:

The jQuery includes:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick.editors.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick.formatters.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick.grid.js"></script>
```

Everything is unedited above.
The code implementing the grid:

```
                        var grid; var cols; var rows; var options = {
                            enableCellNavigation: true,
                            enableColumnReorder: false,
                            forceFitColumns: true
                        };
*rows and cols come from server side via JSON.parse*
grid = new Slick.Grid("#results", rows, cols, options);
```

The code, which comes from the server and fills up the rows and cols variable is basically this:

```
            cols:
            echo json_encode('[
                    {"id":"price",      "name":"Ár",                "field":"price"},
                    {"id":"location",   "name":"Elhelyezkedés",     "field":"location"},
                    {"id":"egyeb",      "name":"Lófasz",            "field":"egyeb"},
                    {"id":"pic",        "name":"Képek",             "field":"pic", "formatter":"Slick.Formatters.PercentComplete"}
                ]');
            rows:
            echo json_encode('[
                    {"price": "5", "location":"AlsóBélaCsecselény",     "egyeb":"lófasz",   "pic":"1",  "link":"ezittahelye"},
                    {"price": "6", "location":"qrsóBéqrcselény",        "egyeb":"lófasz",   "pic":"2",  "link":"ezittahelye"},
                    {"price": "7", "location":"AlsóBélaqwqwrelény",     "egyeb":"lófasz",   "pic":"3",  "link":"ezittahelye"},
                    {"price": "8", "location":"qwrCsecselény",          "egyeb":"lófasz",   "pic":"4",  "link":"ezittahelye"}
                ]');
```

Everything works fine, when the pic column does not have a formatter, and the grid works with extra properties for the columns as well, such as a mistyped "formatter" tag(like "fformatter" or whatever),

but the Javascript gives me the following error every time the JSON code has a "formatter" property:

Uncaught exception: TypeError: 'getFormatter(row, m)' is not a function

every damn time I try to load the table, the formatters mess up everything and I don't know what to do next! I tried to track back the bug, and it lead me to the 1124. line of the source code of slick.grid.js, this function somehow breaks everything with the return statement..

```
function getFormatter(row, column) {
  var rowMetadata = data.getItemMetadata && data.getItemMetadata(row);

  // look up by id, then index
  var columnOverrides = rowMetadata &&
      rowMetadata.columns &&
      (rowMetadata.columns[column.id] || rowMetadata.columns[getColumnIndex(column.id)]);

  return (columnOverrides && columnOverrides.formatter) ||
      (rowMetadata && rowMetadata.formatter) ||
      column.formatter ||
      (options.formatterFactory && options.formatterFactory.getFormatter(column)) ||
      options.defaultFormatter;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Here's how I get the the code from the server:

```
                            $.post( "queries.php?event=search&&phase=columns", $("#full_search").serialize(), function(data){
                                    cols = JSON.parse(data);
                                    alert(cols[1].id);
                                    $.post( "queries.php?event=search&&phase=rows", $("#full_search").serialize(), function(data){
                                        rows = JSON.parse(data);
                                        alert(rows[1].link);
                                        grid = new Slick.Grid("#results", rows, cols, options);
                                        alert(grid.getData().length);
                                        return false;
                                    },"json");
                                return false;
                            },"json");
                            },"json");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Slick.Formatters.PercentComplete` shouldn't be a string.  It's a function (class constructor) defined in slick.formatters.js.

Comment: edited the post to show how I get the JSON through a post call. Is there any way around this? If I discard the apostrophes from the "Slick.Formatters.PercentComplete" then the hole script will break at the JSON.parse line.

Comment: Change "formatter":"Slick.Formatters.PercentComplete" to "formatter":Slick.Formatters.PercentComplete.

Comment: then the hole script will break at the JSON.parse line.. is there a way around this? I'm not sure how else should I be sending the JSON code through the post request

Comment: yea, it's not json.  it's a javascript object.  don't know what you need to do with php there.

Comment: maybe if I change the last column's formatter tag's value from string to Javascript object?

Comment: Alright I solved it!

I parsed the data, and then set the formatter string to an object:
          cols = JSON.parse(data);
          cols[3].formatter = Slick.Formatters.PercentComplete;

and that does it! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> Alright I solved it! I parsed the data, and then set the formatter string to an object: cols = JSON.parse(data); cols[3].formatter = Slick.Formatters.PercentComplete; and that does it! Thank you for your help!

I would suggest something like this.

Slick.Formatters.PercentComplete is a function and there is no functions in json as shown in http://json.org. Also, validation fails in a JSON that has a function. You can try validate here: http://jsonlint.com/.

**You can´t have functions in JSON**. Then, after receiving the 'almost JSON' data, you need parse it on the client with javascript, like you did.

Thanks for your sample!
I´m having the same problem and it was helpful.

In my case I get metadata with jQuery Ajax:

```
req = $.ajax({type: 'GET',
              url: url,
              dataType: 'json',
              async: false}).done(function(meta) { metadata = meta; });
```

The metadata returned is something like this:

```
{"errors":{}, 
 "columns":[{"formatter":"TaskNameFormatter",
             "field":"1",
             "id":"1","width":220,"name":"Hierarchy1","cssClass":"cell-title"},
             OTHERS_COLUMNS]}
```

Realize that the formatter is still a string. Then I go through all columns changing the formatter from String to Function with this code:

```
  $.each(metadata.columns, function(index, value) {
                              if(typeof value.formatter != "undefined") {
                                 value.formatter = eval(value.formatter);
                              } 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

For users with data coming thru JSON, the object call must still be wrapped in quotes; however, I was able to find in the `slick.grid.js` file the part where it was bailing:

```
if (d) {
  if(m.formatter){m.formatter=eval(m.formatter)} // make it an object call instead of string
  stringArray.push(getFormatter(row, m)(row, cell, value, m, d));
}
```